# Laravel placing content of <header> into <body>?

Tags: php, laravel

I have googled this and, while some people have the same issue, it is obvious what is causing their problem (missing @endsection, etc.)

In my case, however, I am quite lost as to why this is happening. It does not happen on the pages generated by Laravel (make:auth pages); but the ones I have made myself it happens on.

layout.app:

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
 <head>
     <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

<title>Student Picker</title>

<!-- Fonts -->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<!-- Styles -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ URL::asset('css/styles.css') }}" />
</head>
<body>
<div class="content">
    @if(Auth::check())
    <div class="links">
        <a href="/home">Profile</a>
        <a href="/courses">My Courses</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    @else
    <div class="links">
        <a href="/">Home</a>
        <a href="/about">About Us</a>
        <a href="/login">Login</a>
        <a href="/register">Register</a>
        <a href="/contact">Contact</a>
    </div>
    @endif
    <main>
        @yield( 'content_header' )
        <hr>
        @yield( 'content' )
    </main>
</div>
</body>
<footer>
  ... scripts ...
</footer>
</html>
```

welcome.blade.php (this one has `<header>` code appearing in `<body>`)

```
@extends('layouts.app');

@section('content_header')
<div class="title m-b-md">
    Student Picker
</div>
@endsection

@section('content')
<div class="content">
    Welcome to the Student Picker! Feel free to explore our website, singup, or login.
</div>
@endsection
```

login.blade.php (this one works fine):

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content_header')
<div class="title m-b-md">
   Login
</div>
@endsection
@section('content')
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
    ...

    </div>
 </div>
 @endsection
```

Comment: Where is the rest of your template? Like the <html> <head> tags... and when you say <header> do you mean <head>?

Comment: I had removed those parts of the template on this post just to improve readability, they are there in the original code though. I updated the OP with the full source.

Comment: You can't have the <footer> outside of the <body>... also I don't see any <header> tags in any of that... what do you mean by "welcome.blade.php (this one has <header> code appearing in <body>)"?

Comment: I moved the footer, but that did not solve the problem. What I mean is that, on the welcome.blade.php, within the actual source code the code that should be within the <head> tags is where it should be. But when actually running the site, if looking in Inspect Element, the <head> code is being output between the <body>...I updated the OP with an image.

Comment: Stack Overflow's servers seem to be slow for me, at the moment. Image here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qOzCZ.jpg

Comment: In the welcome.blade.php you have a semicolon ... "@extends('layouts.app');"

Comment: Ah! That fixed it! Sweet, thanks!